# Eclipse running lift project (project configuration issues)

Tags: eclipse, maven, lift, scala-ide

Trying to get a lift project to run on windows, I've installed `maven` on my computer, then tried to use

`mvn archetype:generate` from `cmd`, then chose the lift basic one , but it always failed on the `jetty:run` part. Before that, I had to change a lot of the pom.xml file to even get a successful build (since the tutorial I was using was obsolete and it couldn't find the dependencies).

So I've decided to try with the `eclipse` plugin, thinking it should be easier.
I've installed the `maven` plugin for `eclipse` and created a project with the `lift archetype`.
The project was succesfully created, but I have all kinds of errors in the editor for missing `;` and so on (I have `scala ide` installed on `eclipse` also and creating a normal scala project works and compiles/runs fine). I have also tried to include the `scala-library.jar` in the `buildpath`, with no change.

***The odd part is that I can run the cmd and go to the project folder, then run `mvn jetty:run` and it will actually work (?!)*** Trying to run in eclipse with `jetty:run` as goal will give me ClassNotFoundException on the HelloWorld snippet.

So what might be wrong with my settings?

UPDATE: no luck whatsoever, after trying 3 different eclipse versions, installing the maven for scala plugin and following every tutorial I could find. It just simply feels all is outdated on the instructions:
this is how it looks after I include the scala libraries for eclipse on every project (after I create it from an archetype):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this "mvn archetype:generate" up to date? I don't know if anybody guarantees it will work at all.. 
Anyway, the default way to at least try Lift and see it working is the following: https://github.com/lift/lift_25_sbt

It uses "Simple Build Tool" instead of maven, but maven should work, too. Also, you can easily read "build.sbt" to get all the dependencies.
Plugins for creating eclipse/intellij project definitions are included. (See the README of the demo project.)

The target to create eclipse project is "eclipse" or "eclipse with-sources=true".
The target to launch the app is "container:start".